# Unity ビルドは成功するがAndoroid端末実機起動時にクラッシュする

Tags: android, unity3d, unity2d

Unityでゲームを作ってAppleStoreやGooglePlayにリリースしています。
しかしこの前突然Androidでの実機で起動するとクラッシュして落ちるようになりました。このログの見方がさっぱり分からず、一方的な質問になってしまうことをお許しください。
以下はその時のLogです。一体どうすればエラーは直るのでしょうか。

```
05/29 17:06:42.519 7804 7852 Info Unity MemoryManager: Using 'Dynamic Heap' Allocator.
05/29 17:06:42.559 7804 7852 Info Unity SystemInfo CPU = ARMv7 VFPv3 NEON, Cores = 4, Memory = 1875mb
05/29 17:06:42.559 7804 7852 Info Unity SystemInfo ARM big.LITTLE configuration: 4 big (mask: 0xf), 0 little (mask: 0x0)
05/29 17:06:42.579 7804 7852 Info Unity ApplicationInfo com.enigma.tank version 1.4.3 build 48293425-3ed5-411f-b9e4-64d8485731a4
05/29 17:06:42.579 7804 7852 Info Unity Built from '2020.3/staging' branch, Version '2020.3.32f1 (12f8b0834f07)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a', Stripping 'Disabled'
05/29 17:06:44.339 7804 7852 Error CRASH *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05/29 17:06:44.339 7804 7852 Error CRASH Version '2020.3.32f1 (12f8b0834f07)', Build type 'Release', Scripting Backend 'il2cpp', CPU 'armeabi-v7a'
05/29 17:06:44.339 7804 7852 Error CRASH Build fingerprint: 'KDDI/KYV34_jp_kdi/KYV34:5.1/104.1.2940/104.1.2940:user/release-keys'
05/29 17:06:44.339 7804 7852 Error CRASH Revision: '0'
05/29 17:06:44.339 7804 7852 Error CRASH ABI: 'arm'
05/29 17:06:44.339 7804 7852 Error CRASH Timestamp: 2022-05-29 17:06:44+0900
05/29 17:06:44.339 7804 7852 Error CRASH pid: 7804, tid: 7852, name: UnityMain  >>> com.enigma.tank
```

Comment: これは単にクラッシュしたというだけのログです。意味のあるログを見たいなら、まず一歩目としてはADB接続してAndroid Device Monitorでログを見るのがよいでしょう。

Answer (score 0):

> bboydaisukeさん
> 質問主のhirano ayumuです。この質問を登録前にゲスト扱いで投稿して、先程本登録を済ませたら別のアカウント扱いになってしまいました。

それで本題に戻るのですがADB接続というのはやったことがありませんので後で調べてやってみようと思います。
話が変わるのですが先程UnityのProject Settings内のScripting BackendをIL2CPPからMonoに変更したらクラッシュしなくなりました。これから何か原因を想定できたりしませんか？

Comment: アカウントが二つに分かれてしまった場合には、ヘルプを参考にアカウントのマージを検討してください。参考: [間違えてアカウントを 2 件作成してしまいました。どうしたらマージできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)